# PNG sequence to MP4 while looping the animation

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

So, I'm trying to convert a PNG sequence to an MP4 and loop the animation about 100 times, the only problem is my script doesn't seem to be working properly.

What the script is supposed to do is get the number of PNG files in the frames directory, and send them to FFMPEG 100 times. Only problem is my script isn't working right. Here's the code.

```
#!/bin/bash

loopcode()
{
tmpdir=frames
picext=png
one=$(ls -l ${tmpdir}/*.png  | wc -l)
two=$(echo "${one}+0" | bc -l)
three=0
while [ ! ${loopi} -eq ${looper} ]; do
  while [ ! ${three} -eq ${two} ]; do
    three=$(printf "%09d" ${two})
    echo ${tmpdir}/${three}.${picext}
    two=$(echo "${two}+1" | bc -l)
  done
  two=0
  loopi=$(echo "${loopi}+1" | bc -l)
done
}

looper=100
loopi=0
outfile=output.mp4
fps=5
convert frames/*.png frames/%09d.jpeg
loopcode && sleep 5
cat $(loopcode) | ffmpeg -framerate 1/5 -i - -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p "${outfile}"
```

Comment: use `set -vx` to turn on shell debug/trace (and `set +vx`) to turn it off. Seeing what values are being assigned to variables is a big help. The `-v` portion will display each block of code before it is executed (including your dbl-while loop), so it may be confusing. If so, try `set -x` and set +x` . Good luck.

Comment: Does `ffmpeg` really accept the images concatenated on standard input??

Comment: It can, if the input format is flagged i.e. `-f image2pipe -i -`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can skip the whole loop part in script and do it with ffmpeg i.e.

```
ffmpeg -r 1/5 -f lavfi -i "movie='a%d.png':loop=100" -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p "${outfile}"
```

This requires that the PNG image names form a continuous sequence.

Comment: I get an error saying "Could find no file with path 'a%d.png' and index in the range 0-4"

Comment: Your images have to be sequentially numbered and start with a i.e. `a000000000.png`, `a000000001.png`, `a000000002.png` ....

Comment: This still doesn't work. All the images are in a directory called "frames", the script is in the same directory that the frames directory is in.

Comment: If I define one of the images, the script seems to work, but not with multiple images.